# Python. displaying items in a random order

Tags: python, random

I'm a beginner at python and i've got this code for a flash card game that I have wrote. The following code is only a small part of it.

```
remove = 0
        while remove < 2: 
            a = random.choice(list(key))    
            if (a) == line27:
                print(a)
                x = input(random.choice(defi))
                x = input(random.choice(defi))
                x = input(line28)

                if x == ('c'):
                    remove = remove + 1
                    print('you got it right')
                    score = (score + 1)
                    print('score =', score)
                if x == ('b', 'a'):
                    print('thats wrong')
                print()
                t = t + 1

                if remove == 2:
                    key.remove(line27)
```

I have to be able to display this :

```
x = input(random.choice(defi))
x = input(random.choice(defi))
x = input(line28)
```

in a random order every time it displays. so the two random choices have to display in different positions and so does the line 28.
the two random choices are in a list and the line 28 is in another list if that is any help.

Comment: A few things: `x` will always be the result of the last assignment statement, and `input` here isn't doing what you think it is. `x` will never equal the _tuple_ `('b','a')`; and finally - you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Presumably you are seeing unexpected output? I guess you are asking for random piece of input from the user? It's hard to tell what you are expecting without greater context, and x is ALWAYS going to be equal to input(line28) so the first two assignments to x are redundant. What is contained in "defi"? What are line28 and line27? What is t? It seems to have no use... I'd like to help you out, but you will have to define the problem more clearly first.

Comment: I know what input does as I have tested it up to here and it works fine. Sorry

Comment: The code runs fine but I just need to know how to make the thre things taht I showed you run in a diffrent order each time they are displayed.

Comment: I'll just edit the question I can put the whole code in put its over 400 lines long. would you like me too add it in or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this be sufficient? It seems like this is what you are asking for, but I don't really know...

```
def randomInput(list):
    randIdx = random.randint(0, len(list)-1)
    in = input(list[randIdx])
    list.remove(randIdx)
    return in, list

inputs = [random.choice(defi), random.choice(defi), line28]
x, inputs = randomInput(inputs)
x, inputs = randomInput(inputs)
x, inputs = randomInput(inputs)
```

Also, as Burhan Khalid said, x is never going to be equal to the tuple ('b', 'a')... I suppose what you meant was

```
x == 'b' or x == 'a'
```